# .htaccess redirection on local server

Tags: .htaccess

One of my doamins has been indexed by Google in various ways, mail.mydomain.com, ftp.mydomain.com, pop.mydomain.com... instead of simply www.mydomain.com.

I have inserted the following two lines in my .htaccess file and this seems to be working well in telling Google to update it's index:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www)\.mydomain\.com [NC]  
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However, when these same two lines are included on the .htaccess file of my local server (127.0.0.1) I can no longer reach 127.0.0.1 as I'm always redirected to www.mydomain.com.

does anybody know how to write these two lines such that I don't have to comment them out on my local server?

Answer (score 1):

I've dealt with that problem by putting the relevant lines into the Apache configuration, and then having separate live and development configurations. They are likely required anyway for file-path reasons and servernames, if nothing else.

Comment: I like your approach, but it makes configuration complicated in terms of having multiple points of configuration